# Deserialize Property with pattern using Jackson

Tags: kotlin, jackson, deserialization

There's a request that i'm using and it's parameter name is __parameter10/02/2020, the date is sent into request.
Is there a way to deserialize this using the Property annotation? Also how can i do this with the custom serializer?
Json Sample:

```
{"yearly_return10/02/2020" : "2.87", "__monthlyreturn_current10/02/2020": "-0.0853703899653",}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try @JsonAnySetter

```kotlin
class Response {
    lateinit var yearlyReturn: BigDecimal
    lateinit var monthlyReturnCurrent: BigDecimal

    @JsonAnySetter
    fun set(key: String, value: String) {
        when {
            key.contains("yearly_return") -> yearlyReturn = BigDecimal(value)
            key.contains("monthlyreturn_current") -> monthlyReturnCurrent = BigDecimal(value)
        }
    }
}

val objectMapper: ObjectMapper = ObjectMapper().registerModules(
        ParameterNamesModule(),
        Jdk8Module(),
        JavaTimeModule(),
        KotlinModule()
)

val response = objectMapper.readValue<Response>("""{"yearly_return10/02/2020" : "2.87", "__monthlyreturn_current10/02/2020": "-0.0853703899653"}""")
```

Comment: Nice! Exactly what i need. Thanks a bunch!